# Is there alternative symbol for congruence classes?

Tags: notation, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

I saw on youtube a talk about the congruence classes. For example, the congruence classes modul0 4 are written as followings.

$[0]_4 = \{0, 4, 8, 12, \dots \} $

$[1]_4 = \{1, 5, 9, 13, \dots \} $

$[2]_4 = \{2, 6, 10, 14, \dots \} $

$[3]_4 = \{3, 7, 11, 15, \dots \} $

Here the square brackets $[]$ with subscript modulus is used defining each congruence class. Since the square brackets $[]$ can also be defined as the round-toward-zero function, wouldn't this be confusing in the proof or article writing? Is there an alternative symbol for the congruence classes modulo m?

Comment: Any notations is fine as far as you define things precisely.

Comment: Also, I don't know about "round towards zero", but "round down" is often denoted with $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$. Also, I've seen the notation $x/_R$ where $x$ is a representative of the class and $R$ is the equivalence relation, so in this case if you use (a bit custom) symbol $\equiv_4$ to mean $\equiv\pmod 4$, you would get $0/_{\equiv_4}$, $1_{/\equiv_4}$, $2/_{\equiv_4}$ and $3/_{\equiv_4}$. Not sure how widely used the latter is.

Comment: You rarely use the rounding function of real numbers together with the modulo function of integers. And if the modulus is added then confusion is almost impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are fewer simple notations than there are simple concepts that need notations, so duplication in inevitable. When the context does not make the meaning clear it's the author's responsibility to make their notation unambiguous. In this case, the author tells you just what the brackets mean. The fact that they may mean something else somewhere else  causes no confusion.